# Multiple Inheritance in C++ with 3 derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to use multiple inheritance. *Person* is my base class. *Student* and *Angestellter* inherit the protected attributes. *WissenschaftlicheHilfskraft* should also inherit these attributes (from Person, Student, Angestellter), but I can't call the method get_name() in my last derived class. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person {
      protected:
              string name;
      public:              //.......
          string get_name() { name = "bob"; return name; }
};

class Student: public Person {
private:    //......
public:     //......
};

class Angestellte: public Person {
private:    //......
public:    //......
};

class WissenschaftlicheHilfskraft : public Student, public Angestellte
{
private: //......
public: //......
};


int main()
{
    Person p;
    cout << p.get_name() << endl;   //WORKS
    Student s;
    cout << s.get_name() << endl;   //WORKS
    Angestellte a;
    cout << a.get_name() << endl;   //WORKS
    WissenschaftlicheHilfskraft wh;
    cout << wh.get_name() << endl;  //DOESN'T WORK
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to look like this: 
[image]

Comment: You can get yourself acquainted here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, other than Paul R's answer your inheritance is wrong. You need to use virtual inheritance like as shown [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-where).

`class Student: public Person {` becomes `class Student: public virtual Person {` and so on. This ensures that only one object of base is created for the final object.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, since it resolves the underlying problem rather than working around it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic "diamond" problem with multiple inheritance. You can work around this by removing the ambiguity, e.g. change:

```
cout << wh.get_name() << endl;  //DOESN'T WORK
```

to:

```
cout << wh.Student::get_name() << endl;  //WORKS
```

However, see [@Shiv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41139809/253056) for a better solution which properly resolves the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)